# Cakephp3 lowercases sql query

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I got a problem with the following snippet of a SQL-Statement:

```
...->where([
        'Vlans.id' => $this->id,
        'AND' => [
            ["TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, Requests.timestamp, CURDATE()) <" => $this->days]
        ]
    ])...
```

Cakephp lowercases some parts (requests.timestamp and curdate):

```
(Vlans.id = :c0 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, requests.timestamp, curdate()) < :c1)
```

Lowercasing the `CURDATE()` isn't a problem because it's a SQL-Function.
But I aliased the requests-table to Requests (uppercase R).

Is there a way to prevent the lowercasing or an other solution to this instead of changing all my aliases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use cake SQL functions

```
$f = $query->func()->timestampdiff([
    'DAY' => 'literal', 
    'Requests.timestamp' => 'identifier', 
    $query->func()->curdate()
]);
$days = $this->days;
$query->where(function ($exp) use ($f,  $days) {
    return $exp->lt($f, $days);
});
```

see the manual [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

Comment: this works. thank you. I stumbled over this part of the documentation. But I didn't understand it.